# Create a table with a varchar as primary key

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

Is there a way of creating a table with a varchar as primary key (in Symfony/Doctrine)?

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `field_one` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `field_two` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field_one`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

When I try to create that using `php bin/console make:entity` it creates an integer id field as primary key.

Also is there a way of making a custom name for integer primary key field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine's annotations works on primary key as well.
Here is an an example:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="field", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
  private $field;
```

You you want to set your id yourself you have to disable generated value strategy:
`@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")`